# How to make a loop in a while statement that resets the entire code OR if user inputs "no" it allows exit

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am doing a guessing game and need the while to loop, which it does, just not accurately. I also need it to have user input to allow it to loop, meaning yes makes it loop and no allows you to exit. I have tried various things to no avail. I would also need help with if the user quits before getting the answer, it apologizes for the user quitting and gives the number of attempts. Here is my code as of now:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExampleCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        Scanner soul = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean repeat = false;
        int computerValue = randomNumber.nextInt(100);
        int attempts = 0;
        int correct = 0;
        int guess = 0;

        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1-100 or 0 to quit: ");

        while (guess != 0 || correct == 0 || !repeat) {
            attempts++;
            guess = soul.nextInt();
            if (guess < 0 || guess > 100) {
                System.out.println("Remember, a number between 1-100! Try again");
            } else if (guess == computerValue) {
                correct++;
                System.out.println("Congratulations you won! Your number of tries was " +
                        " attemps " + " and the number was: " + computerValue);
                System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Type yes or no");
                Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
                String go = ask.nextLine();
                if (go.equals("yes")) {
                    repeat = true;
                }

            } else if (guess < computerValue) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too low!");
            } else if (guess > computerValue) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too high!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Javascript and Java are two completely different languages. Your question is about Java, not Javascript

Comment: I should also mention it has to be a sentinal input to determine whether the user wants to quit

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Comment: Please, 1) format your code; 2) leave appropriate tags; 3) narrow down your question to the particular snippet/question.

Answer (score 0):

You want this to run the loop at least once, so check the loop condition at the end using a DO-WHILE.

On a correct guess where you output the number of attempts, you have the variable inside the string (and spelled incorrectly) so you won't see the value as expected.

You can simplify the loop condition. Keep asking the user for answers until they type 0 or say NO after a correct answer. On correct answer, if they say no, simply set guess to 0.

```
do
{
    attempts++;
    
    guess = soul.nextInt();
    
    if (guess < 0 || guess > 100) {
        System.out.println("Remember, a number between 1-100! Try again");
        
    } else if (guess == computerValue) {
        correct++;
        
        System.out.println("Congratulations you won! Your number of tries was " +  attempts + " and the number was: " + computerValue);
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Type yes or no");
        
        Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
        String go = ask.nextLine();
        
        if(go.equals("yes")){
            guess = 0;
        }
    } else if (guess < computerValue) {
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low!");
        
    } else if (guess > computerValue) {
        System.out.println("Your guess is too high!");
    }
}while (guess != 0)
```

Comment: I realized I did forget to put attempts++ in the correct else if statement, however it seems I cannot run this attempt due to the while (guess!=0) at the end of the function. I attempted to use a do-while before asking the question and I failed sadly. I do not where how to fix the while problem as I am new and I learned this all very recently.

Comment: I kind of got a fix by adding brackets and when I guess correctly and ask to play again, i type yes and it kills the code.

Comment: When I type 0 to exit, it allows exit but also says guess is too low! I have had that problem for awhile and have tried plenty of ways to fix it however I can't seem to find a solution. Also, it allows me to replay when I say no but it does not display any text, it just allows me to input a number and that is when it restarts. I wish I had the answers after plenty of videos and guides but I am struggling a lot with this problem.

Comment: You can simply add an addition check to that line, if (guess < computerValue && guess > 0)

Comment: I figured out a fix that may (?) be temporary being making that last while (guess!= 0) say "Thank you for playing the guessing game. Have a good rest of your day!". I also changed the if(go.equals("yes") to "no" which allowed that to work. I also added an else if(go.equals("yes")){
            computerValue = randomNumber.nextInt(100);
            continue;} which seems to maybe not be doing anything. When I say yes and start attempting, I am trying to make the random number BE random, as right now it chooses one random one at first and then says everything is too low.

Comment: Oh, I got rid of continue and that fixed that last problem!

Answer (score 0):

Please use following method. Hope you will get expected results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    Scanner soul = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean repeat = false; 
    boolean bored = false;  //1
    int computerValue = randomNumber.nextInt(100);
    int attempts = 0;
    int correct = 0;
    int guess = 0;
    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1-100 or 0 to quit: ");

    while (guess != 0 || correct == 0 || !repeat)
    {
        attempts++;
        guess = soul.nextInt();
        if (guess < 0 || guess > 100)
        {
            System.out.println("Remember, a number between 1-100! Try again");

        }
        else if (guess == computerValue)
        {
            correct++;
            System.out.println("Congratulations you won! Your number of tries was " +
                " attemps " + " and the number was: " + computerValue);
            
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Type yes or no");
            Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
            String go = ask.nextLine();
            if(go.equals("yes"))
            {
                repeat = true;
                attempts = 0;
                computerValue = randomNumber.nextInt(100);
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (guess < computerValue) 
        {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low!");
        }
        else if (guess > computerValue) 
        {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too high!");
        }
        
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Type yes or no");
            Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
            String go = ask.nextLine();
            if(go.equals("yes"))
            {
                repeat = true;
            }
            else if (go.equals("no"))
            {
                bored = true;
                repeat = false;
                break;
            }

    }
    If(bored)
    System.out.println("Apology If you get bored. Your number of tries was " +
                " attemps " + " and the number was: " + computerValue);
    else
    System.out.println("Bye Bye. Hope you will play again");
    
}
```

Comment: I tried testing this code to a problem where it would ask for a number, I would input it, and then it would ask if I want to play again, input yes or no over and over each time i put a new input.

Comment: No problem....Use continue in else if (guess < computerValue) 
            {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too low!"); continue;
            }
            else if (guess > computerValue) 
            {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too high!"); continue;
            }

Answer (score 0):

In probably-every programming language these days, the following strategy is very often used:

• `while (true) {` ... *intended to be "a signal of what is to follow ..."*

• When you find that something is wrong, `continue`.  (The loop starts over.)

• When everything is hunky-dory, `break`.  (The loop ends.)

*(Various [recent ...] languages might use different keywords, but they're there.)*

This actually turns out to be a very **clean** way of expressing this extremely-common situation, and every [subsequent ...] programmer will recognize it instantly.  The only thing that you must be very sure of is that *every* possibility within this "endless" loop actually winds up at one alternative or the other.

Of course, a key element of this strategy is that "the decision is made, *and then executed* at the time it is made."  There are only two possible `gotos` ... either to the top of the loop, or out of it. Nowhere else. You always know exactly where the code is going to take you – and you always know that it will take you there *right now.*

Comment: I am very new to coding and I had a hard time recognizing where I would apply the methods that you said. I would like to especially use goto but I do not know how I would go about that.

Comment: I would also like to implement the continue function.